# Why are there two different ways of initializing a pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers

The first way looks like this:

```
int *p_number = &number;
```

And the second like:

```
int *p_number;
p_number = &number;
```

I don't get why the first way look as it looks, because I get that `p_number` is the address of `int *p_number` and we are basically giving `p_number` the address of `number` with the `&` operator. But why do we initialize `*p_number` with `&number`? Wouldn't that mean that the pointee of `p_number` is the address of number?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe what's confusing you is the syntax

```
int *p_number = &number;
```

well, you can rewrite it as

```
int* p_number = &number;
```

which is same as

```
int *p_number;
p_number = &number;
```

The first one is actually a combined step of definition and initialization.

Comment: Agreed. This is a big reason why I wish the predominate syntax was "<behavior> <name>", where `int*` is the 'behavior' definition, and `p_number` is the name definition.

Comment: Very confusing style. Why is it like that? I don't see a reason why the * is on the name and not on the type.

Comment: @DennisvonEich actually, it is not _on_ anything, you are free to use any style that suits you. People have different opinions, you know. :)

Comment: @DennisvonEich, the reason why sometimes people prefer the first syntax is because the star character is actually qualifying the variable and not the type.  For example, the declaration  `int* p, n;` may lead you to believe that both `p` and `n` are pointers to `int` while in reality, `p` is a pointer to `int` and `n` is a plain `int`.

Answer (score 3):

Only the first of these is initializing the pointer.  The second creates an uninitialized pointer, and then assigns a value to it.  The net effect of these is the same (you have a pointer variable that points at a particular thing), and the code generated by the compiler is likely identical.

The thing that seems to be confusing you is that the syntax of declarations and initializers is subtly different from the syntax of assignments.  In particular, a `*` in a declaration means that you are declaring a pointer and *not* dereferencing it, while in an expression, a `*` means that you *are* dereferencing.  This kind of subtle difference is considered a wart by some and a feature by others.

Answer (score 0):

```
int *p_number = &number;
```

This consists of two parts: a declartion of `p_number`, followed by its initializer `= &number` (read as "is address of number").

```
int *p_number;
p_number = &number;
```

This does the same, but is conceptually a bit different. The first line is the declaration (same as in previous example). The second line is an *assigment* and it is a statement.